# How to change the color of the bar in barchart if the data is negative - Angular Charts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bar-chart, chart.js, angular-chart

I have created a horizontal barchart with Angular Charts.The HTML looks like this:

```
    <canvas id="base" class="chart-horizontal-bar"
            chart-data="vm.chartData" 
            chart-labels="vm.chartLabels">
    </canvas>
```

The JavaScript variables look like this :

```
 var vm = this;
 vm.chartData = [10,20,-30,40,50];
 vm.chartLabels = ["A","B","C","D","E"];
```

I want to change the color of the bar to red for negative data(in this case -30) and all the bars with positive data should be green (10,20,40,50).

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would loop through your `chartData` and using a condition build out your array for colors. Fair warning, I'm not familiar with Angular Charts, so `vm.chartColors` may not be the right syntax, but the idea here holds, which is to build an array of your colors based on negative/positive numbers in your data. A quick look at angularcharts.js implied you can set the colors with an argument to override the default colors.

```js
var vm = this;
vm.chartData = [10,20,-30,40,50];
vm.chartLabels = ["A","B","C","D","E"];
var colors = [];
for(i=0; i < vm.chartData.length; i++) {
  if (vm.chartData[i] < 0) {
    colors[i] = "rgb(255,0,0)";
  } else {
    colors[i] = "rgb(0,255,0)";
  }
}
vm.chartColors = colors;
console.log(vm.chartColors);
```